# Python split string inside a numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

I have an numpy array like this

> Input

```
array([['ATS1, ATS2', 'P_CD'],
       ['ATS1,ATS2,ATS3', 'C_CD']], dtype=object)
```

I would like to convert this numpy array as stated below

> Expected output

```
array([['ATS1' , 'ATS2', 'P_CD'],
       ['ATS1','ATS2','ATS3', 'C_CD']], dtype=object)
```

As you can notice above, I would like to split the string with a delimeter and make it as a separate entry

Any suggestions on how to achieve using python?

Comment: There is no reason to do this with numpy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use re.split and join
**This is just changing the type but this results in numpy array of lists as inside sub lists can be of variable length so they will not be of numpy array types.**

```
import numpy as np
import re

arr = np.array([['ATS1, ATS2', 'P_CD'],
       ['ATS1,ATS2,ATS3', 'C_CD']], dtype=object)
arr = np.array([re.split('[-,]','-'.join(ele)) for ele in arr] ,dtype=object)
print(arr)
```

Comment: Yes it converts as expected but it is not ending up with numpy array instead it throws as a list. Can u update the solution with numpy array?

Comment: @Vinodprime. Just do `np.array(...)` on the result. And if you don't plan on having uniform elements, numpy is probably not what you want anyway. For string operations, stick with lists.